# Why does my email display in Gmail but not in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email

Thankfully, I sent out a few test emails before sending it out to our email list but this email displays perfectly in gmail but is completely broken when viewed in Outlook.

I'm very new to HTML / CSS (a.k.a 1-month) and I'm wondering if there's a resource out there that essentially translates snippets and tells you which browsers it will and will not work on?
P.S - We're sending out our emails via Mailchimp

Here's the code (too long for StackOverflow): https://github.com/ElF3Rninator/Test/blob/main/Crescent%20Online%20Responsive%20Email%20%20(1).html

Broken Outlook:
[Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEBV.png)

Correctly Rendered Gmail:
[Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpyeR.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook you have to change the format of emails to except HTML.

**Change the format of all new messages**
On the File tab, choose Options > Mail.

Under Compose messages, in the Compose messages in this format list, click HTML, Plain Text, or Rich Text.

Gmail Works with HTML out of the box.